# Fullpage JS: prevent from snapping to top or bottom

Tags: fullpage.js

Just need help on disabling the autoscroll of fullpage.js. I already added the option bigSectionsDestination: null but still it snaps to the bigger section.

here's what I have:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
            autoScrolling: false,
            scrollBar: false,
            bigSectionsDestination: null
)};
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just use the option `fitToSection:false`.
As detailed in the [fullPage.js docs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js):

> **fitToSection:** (default true) Determines whether or not to fit sections to the viewport or not. When set to true the current active section will always fill the whole viewport. Otherwise the user will be free to stop in the middle of a section (when )